# .net vs JS regex issue

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I have a pretty complicated regex that i have finally managed to work in JS

```
  ^\s*((\(\s*([^]+\"|[@#a-zA-Z0-9_-åäöøæüßÅÄÖØÆÜ\-]+){1}(\s{1,}OR\s{1,}(\"[^\"]+\"|[@#a-zA-Z0-9_-åäöøæüßÅÄÖØÆÜ\-]+))*\s*\)))((\s{1,}(AND|NEAR(\/(100|[0-9][0-9]?)(?=\s))?)\s{1,})(\(\s*(\"[^\"]+\"|[@#a-zA-Z0-9_-åäöøæüßÅÄÖØÆÜ\-]+){1}(\s{1,}OR\s{1,}(\"[^\"]+\"|[@#a-zA-Z0-9_-åäöøæüßÅÄÖØÆÜ\-]+))*\s*\)))?(\s{1,}(AND\s{1,}NOT)\s{1,}(\(\s*(\"[^\"]+\"|[@#a-zA-Z0-9_-åäöøæüßÅÄÖØÆÜ\-]+){1}(\s{1,}OR\s{1,}(\"[^\"]+\"|[@#a-zA-Z0-9_-åäöøæüßÅÄÖØÆÜ\-]+))*\s*\)))?(?=(\s*\))?(\;)?\s*$)
```

with the text: (TITLE: "asdasd")

But when i send the text to my C# backend and uses the same regex it failes. 
Is there anywhere i can find out why it failes? I have tried some different online tools but none of them explain why it doesn't work.

I just need to be pointed in the right direction here since i'm pretty new working with regex. Thanks!

Comment: If you show us what strings you have, we might be of help simplifying your expression.

Comment: what do you mean by strings? Do you need more strings than the regex and the test string provided?

Comment: _"the same regex"_ Are you sure it's the _same_ regex - eg you've got the string escaping correct on the conversion to/from C# from JS - perhaps post exactly how you're using it in both JS and C#.

Comment: yeah i'm pretty sure of that. I acctually store the regexes in my backend and i call a method in my js to grab them from the backend. Also the js part is working as i want and i guess there is no need to escape the string when i create the regex string and test it in the same class of my c# code?

Comment: I have tried it in this two: js: https://regex101.com/ and .net: http://regexstorm.net/tester and there i get the same result. the test is working in regex101 and not in regexstorm :(

Comment: `[^]` is not a valid token in .net syntax. `[\s\S]` should work in both.

Comment: But it is uses in in the regex string. And it is a valid regex expression i think. Or do you mean it is not a valid .net regex token?

Comment: @DanielGustafsson: Yes, more strings would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `[^]` that you use in your expression. In JS syntax, it matches any character including newlines. In .net syntax, this is not a valid regex token.

You should be able to use `[\s\S]` as a replacement in both, matching any character including newlines.

Comment: @DanielGustafsson Don't use `[\s\S]`, use `.` and pass the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option to the regex compiler. Native ways are always more efficient and more readable.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I considered that, but afair there is no single-line option for JS regex.

Comment: I mean that `.` and `RegexOptons.Singleline` should be used in C#.

Comment: @Wiktor If I read it correctly OP wants to use the same regex for both. If that is not needed, your comment should be prefered (and the JS regex could remain unchanged)

Comment: Yeah i store them in the backend so that i have them in one place. Thanks tho!